# How to find programs using DNS on a network/machine

Tags: domain-name-system, local-area-network

I have making a server switch. I am using wireshark and seeing that some PCs on my network are using DNS to make requests to the old server. I would like to track this down but do not know how. I imagine I need to first narrow down what programs on my network use DNS, however, I do not even know how to do that. I have tried googling for means of doing just that but am coming up short. Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Comment: Why? Just go to those machines and change the DNS entries. Almost any program on a PC with network connectivity will make DNS requests.

Comment: If you're using Wireshark to see the DNS requests then it also shows the Source IP of those requests. So... what's your question exactly??

Comment: Thanks. I guess I had a misunderstanding of DNS. I was seeing it crop up but I knew at least most PCs weren't using it. Come to find there was a cell phone connected to a wifi that was using the old one. Decided to just take it completely offline and see what broke. All seems to be in order. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With few exceptions*, programs don't talk to DNS servers; operating systems do. You have the IP addresses of the machines talking to the old server, so go fix those machines.

* Email server applications are sometimes configured to talk to DNS servers directly.

Answer (score 3):

When I've moved DNS servers before, what I've done is:

1. Set up the new server (sounds like you've got that)
2. Move the machines I think use the old one to the new one
3. Set up logging (or wireshark) on the old one of every query to find machines I've missed
4. If anything shows up, GOTO 2